# How to call an InputKey from within a Task in an SBT Plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to make a `task` execute several `inputKey`.

```
myTask := Def.taskDyn {
   val outputOfMyInputKey = myInputKey.[WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE].value

   Def.task {
      // do something with outputOfMyInputKey
   }
}
```

Anybody knows how to call `inputKey` with default parameters ?

I tried `parsed` , `evaluated`, `value`, `inputTaskValue` but none of them works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this section of the sbt docs: [Get a Task from an InputTask](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Input-Tasks.html#Get+a+Task+from+an+InputTask). You can use `.toTask` to provide input for your input task:

```
myInputKey.toTask("").value
```

Notice that if you provide a non-empty input, it should start with a space:

```
myInputKey.toTask(" arg1 arg2").value
```